# Python crashing on Mac

Tags: python, macos, graphics, crash

I just download a graphics module (found at http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/) and wrote a quick program to test it out. All it is supposed to do is create a window. It works, but the second the window is created Python (not IDLE) goes non-responsive and I have to force quit. What could be causing this? The code (that they provide as an example) is:

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin("My Circle", 100, 100)
    c = Circle(Point(50,50), 10)
    c.draw(win)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
```

After I click it suddenly crashes.

Comment: Post your code and we might be able to help you out.

Comment: `I know my code is correct` ... famous last words :). Is it possible that the python code is waiting on something from the window you've created? If it's only one line, post it. We may be able to spot something (or at least try it ourselves).

Comment: @ccoakley I've used zellegraphics for class exercises before and this is likely the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually expected behavior. The line

```
win.getMouse()
```

hangs the interpreter and window until you click. After the click, the line

```
win.close()
```

destroys the window, then your program terminates. This may appear as a "crash" to you, but is actually the expected end of your Python program's run. (If you're getting an error, post the trace in your question.)